# Database structure for tags system

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization, normalization

I'm making a simple PHP Forum, whereby tags are created alongside the main topic.

The table looks like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topic` (
  `topic_id ` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_head` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `topic_body` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `topic_tag` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `topic_date` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `topic_owner` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Specifically for the tags, I'll be performing a select query in the form of:

```
$tags = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT topic_tags
                       FROM forum_topics")
                       while($tags = mysql_fetch_assoc($tags){   
                       $split_tags  = "$tags";
                       $pieces = explode(",", $split_tags);
```

Currently, topic_tags are in the format `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4` 
How can I have it in such a way that each topic tag will be associated with each topic?

Comment: can you clarify your question, what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, what you want is another table for tags and then a third table to store the relationships. So:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `t_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_text` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `t_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `tag_pairs` (
  `tp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tp_topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tp_tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tp_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tp_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`tp_topic_id`) REFERENCES topic('topic_id'), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`tp_tag_id`) REFERENCES tags('t_id') 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Then, to get tags for a topic based on its ID ($THIS_ID):

```
$query = mysql_query("
  SELECT tags.t_text 
  FROM tags, tag_pairs, topic 
  WHERE topic.topic_id = '$THIS_ID'
  AND tag_pairs.tp_topic_id = topic.topic_id 
  AND tag_pairs.tp_tag_id = tags.t_id 
 ");
```

Comment: Yep, and variable sanitization (or PDO). I was just trying to get the gist of it over.

Comment: I just feel that FK constraints are part of normalization and your answer doesn't hit on that.

Comment: What if I add `t_id` to my topic table and create a new table for tags like you suggested. Thereby eliminating your second table.?

Comment: That will work if you only have one tag per topic. Didn't you want multiple tags per topic though?

Answer (score 0):

Call the columns just: `id`, `head`, `body`, `tag_id (FK)`, `date` and `user_id (FK)`

This is much more understandable and also easier to use. Let me explain:

Right now you are using the columns as: `topic_id`, but it should be: `topic.id`. How do you get this? By simply using the `tablename + column`. So when the table is called `topics` and you have a column called `id`, you can use it by saying: `topics.id`. In the answer above from da5id, I can see that he is using `topics.topic_id`, a bit overkill isn't it? ;)

Also, read this article about [database normal form 3](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/) and google a bit yourself with [database+3nf](https://www.google.nl/search?q=database+3nf)

Comment: "topics.topic_id' came from the OP's table schema :)